# PropsKeys.DOCKBAR_ADMINISTRATIVE_LINKS_SHOW_IN_POP_UP cannot be resoved when i updated a portlet from liferay 6.2 to 7

Tags: liferay-7

I migrated my portlet with code upgrade tool from 6.2 to 7.In my .jsp page.

I get an error:

> **The PropsKeys.DOCKBAR_ADMINISTRATIVE_LINKS_SHOW_IN_POP_UP cannot be**
>   **resolved**

How can I replace it.
My code:

```
    if (GetterUtil.getBoolean(PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.DOCKBAR_ADMINISTRATIVE_LINKS_SHOW_IN_POP_UP)))
     {
     }
```

Comment: it is just a config setting. You can look it up how it was used in 6.2 and add this property to portal-ext.properties that will fit your UC. Is this in your portlet or in some hook code?

Comment: Its in my custom login portlet.That constant is not available with liferay 7

Comment: I know. It was removed but you can add the property and add your own constant. Something like ```PropsUtil.get(LegacyPropsKeys.DOCKBAR_ADMINISTRATIVE_LINKS_SHOW_IN_POP_UP))```

Comment: where i should add my own constant? the thing is the portlet was developed by another company.I just do the migration to 7 and i am new to Liferay.

Comment: Create a class LegacyPropsKeys put the constant in and add the class to the portlet source code.